# Instead of ExternalActivityClient can we use DynamicActivityClient in Amazon SWF workflow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I am trying to re-use a code which has been written with DynamicActivityClient. Can I reuse the code by implementing a new implementation of the defined activities?

The call to activityClient.scheduleActivity() fails.

Comment: Could you provide more information about what you are trying to do and what exactly the problem you are facing? As generated code relies on DynamicActivityClient it is certainly can be reused for other scenarios without problem.

Comment: I have a worker Impl which uses Dynamic client to schedule activities. The problem on the console. It fails after decision tasks as it is not able to queue task on ActivityWorker. Which is running as a bean.

Comment: Still not enough info. Exact description of the failure ideally with a stack trace and the activity invocation code would be helpful.